# How to make text gradiently shade at the end of a scrolling area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a horizontally scrollable area. As you can see, there are white-to-transparent gradient rectangles on the left and on the right of the area on top of the scrollable content. What I am trying to do is to make scrollable items fade when they are near the left or the right end - now it looks more or less acceptable. The issue is with the semi-transparent background of the scroller container, you can see yellow map below. If there was an opaque background, it would be easy to implement. But as I have it semi-transparent, I need a solution how to make these rectangles fit the color around it somehow so that white rectangles wouldn't be that prominent.

Is there a right elegant way to do this without much hacking?

[image: Scrollable area with shades at its ends]

Comment: You could absolutely position two divs, one left, one right, with a transparent PNG background on them. It's not hacky, but it is a technique often used. That's going to be by far your easiest solution until CSS can really catch up.

Comment: The issue here is that this png file will be put on another semi-transparent background and it will cause it looks like white rectangle as it does on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a non standard CSS property (that works in Chrome and Safari at the moment called `-webkit-background-clip` ([demo](http://trentwalton.com/bgclip/)) that works like this:

```
.masked{
  background: url(/bgclip/img/paint.png) repeat, white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

The [Can I use page](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts) suggests that it has broad support, but the value you want `text` seems web kit specific.